# How to display nested JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, each, getjson

I have the following JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "meeting_team_members": [
      {
        "team_member_name": "teammember2",
        "team_member_email": "teammember2@email.com",
        "full_image": "\/media\/no-image.png"
      }
    ],
    "meeting_time": "19:45:00",
    "meeting_title": "THIS IS MEETING 1",
    "meeting_date": "2015-08-04"
  },
  {
    "meeting_team_members": [
      {
        "team_member_name": "teammember2",
        "team_member_email": "teammember2@email.com",
        "full_image": "\/media\/no-image.png"
      }
    ],
    "meeting_time": "19:45:00",
    "meeting_title": "THIS IS MEETING 2",
    "meeting_date": "2015-08-04"
  }
]
```

I am using jQuery `getJSON` to display the output in my `html`:

```
    $.getJSON( get_meetings_url, function( data ) {
        $('#json').empty();

        var items = [];

        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            items.push("<li>"+value.meeting_title+" - "+value.meeting_team_members+"</li>");
        });
    });
```

However, when I try to call `value.meeting_team_members` in `items_push` it returns `[object Object]`. How do I iterate over the nested `meeting_team_members`?

**EDIT**

I'd like the HTML output to be as follows:

```
<ul>
<li>meeting_title</li>
<ul><li>meeting_team_members.team_member_name</li></ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: The same way you iterate over the outer data structure, with `$.each`.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, so I would do that inside `items.push( ##code here)`?

Comment: Hint: Nested objects == Nested For loops :)

Comment: Probably not. You first have to think about what you want to convert `meeting_team_members` to (i.e. how do you want to represent it in HTML?). That should be done before `items.push`.

Comment: Thanks, so say I want to keep it simple and have the output as per my edit, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer for those who are interested:

```
    // create JSON
    $.getJSON( get_meetings_url, function( data ) {
        $('#json').empty();

        var items = []
        var team_items = []

        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            items.push("<li>"+value.meeting_title+"</li>")

            $.each(value.meeting_team_members, function(index, value){
                items.push("<ul><li>"+value.team_member_name+"</li></ul>")
            });
        });


        if (items.length == 0){
            $('#json').html('<h2>Empty</h2>')
        }
        else{
            $('#json').html('<h2>Meetings</h2><ul>' + items.join("")+"</ul>")

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the working solution for your problem.

```
function ShowMeetings() {

        var data = [
                      {
                          "meeting_team_members": [
                          {
                              "team_member_name": "teammember2",
                              "team_member_email": "teammember2@email.com",
                              "full_image": "\/media\/no-image.png"
                          }
                        ],
                          "meeting_time": "19:45:00",
                          "meeting_title": "THIS IS MEETING 1",
                          "meeting_date": "2015-08-04"
                      },
                      {
                          "meeting_team_members": [
                          {
                              "team_member_name": "teammember2",
                              "team_member_email": "teammember2@email.com",
                              "full_image": "\/media\/no-image.png"
                          }
                        ],
                          "meeting_time": "19:45:00",
                          "meeting_title": "THIS IS MEETING 2",
                          "meeting_date": "2015-08-04"
                      }
                ];

        $('#json').empty();

        var ul = CreateMeetingsUL(data);

        $('#json').html(ul);
    }

function CreateMeetingsUL(data) {
        var ul = "<ul>";
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            ul += "<li>" + value.meeting_title + "</li>";
            ul += CreateTeamMembersUL(value.meeting_team_members);
        });
        ul += "</ul>";

        return ul;
    }

function CreateTeamMembersUL(data) {
        var ul = "<ul>";
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            ul += "<li>" + value.team_member_name + "</li>";
        });
        ul += "</ul>";

        return ul;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library that does this already, like [renderjson](https://github.com/caldwell/renderjson).

To implement it yourself, you could write a recursive function. If the element you're about to print is an array or object, you want to make a recursive call and print out that item's contents.

Turns out it's pretty simple:

```
function print_json(obj) {
    var ul = $("<ul>");

    for (var i in obj) {
        var li = $("<li>");

        li.append(document.createTextNode(i + ": "));

        if (typeof obj[i] === "object") {
            li.append(print_json(obj[i]));
        } else {
            li.append(document.createTextNode(obj[i]));
        }

        ul.append(li);
    }

    return ul;
}
```

Basically, if we ever call the function, we're expecting to get back a new `ul` element, so we create one at the start and append to it.

Then, we loop over each of the items in the given object. It could be an array, another object, or just a string, integer, or other primitive.

In each iteration, we want to create a new `li`. Then, we append the key (for arrays, it's the index; for objects, it's your specified key when instantiating the object). And finally, we check if the item we want to print is another object (the `typeof` an array evaluates to `object`, so it works for arrays, too). If it is, we call the function recursively on the object to get the `ul` for that.

If not, we just append the text node for the item itself.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/mcunzwnc/) it is in action.

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example please?

Comment: @alias51: Edited with a basic example. It's pretty easy to modify it to fit your needs if necessary.